# Custom to daven Maariv motsei Shabbos for the omud prior to yahrzeit

Tags: tefilla, minhag, yahrtzeit

What is the source of the Minhag to daven Ma'ariv Motsei Shabbos for the Omud prior to one's Yahrzeit the coming week ?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Moish. Great to have you!

Comment: Please edit to conform with https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/759

Answer (score 1):

ספר גשר החיים פרק לב ס"ק ב

ומתפלל לפני התיבה תפלת ערבית במוצאי שבת שקודם האהרצייט ורמז לזה בשער המצוות בשם האר"י זלה"ה

ובהגהה בגשר החיים שם כתב ושמענו מהרב ברוך דוד זלדוביץ ז"ל הוספת טעם למנהג התפלה במוצ"ש 
שקודם היאצ"ט  דהנה כל מוצ"ש עוזבת הנשמה היתרה לאדם ע"מ לחזור אליו בשבת הבא, ואילו במוצ"ש האחרון שלו פרחה ממנו שלא ע"מ לחזור אליו. נמצא שמוצ"ש שקודם פטירתו היתה לו בחינת מיתה מנשמתו היתירה ולכן נחשב המוצ"ש ההוא ג"כ ליא"צ. .

Sefer Gesher Hachaim 32:2

One should pray before the *amud* at the evening prayer on the Saturday night preceding the *Yahrtzeit* [This is alluded to in *Sha'ar Ha-Mitzvot* in the name of the *Arizal*.

And in the footnote of גשר החיים, the the author writes that he heard from Rabbi Baruch David Zeldovich obm an additional reason to the custom of prayer on  Motzei Shabbat, which precedes the *Yahrtzeit*: Every Saturday night, the *Neshamah Yesaira* - The extra soul which enters for Shabbos - leaves the person to return to him on the following Shabbos, but on the last Shabbos night of his life, the person's *Neshamah Yesaira* left him, never to return again, thus, that Shabbat night, before his death, was the *Yahrtzeit* to the departing of the *Neshamah Yesaira*.